# Coffeescript class losing functions

Tags: class, function, coffeescript

I have a CoffeeScript which I can't call functions from. But if I declare an instance of it and add functions to the instance it works. What am I missing?

Function doesn't get called:

```
  class testClass 
    username: 'Fred'

    this.testFunction = ()->
      alert 'test'

  test = new testClass

  test.testFunction()
```

Function works:

```
  class testClass 
    username: 'Fred'

  test = new testClass

  test.testFunction = ()->
    alert 'test'

  test.testFunction()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the `class` body, `this` points to the class itself, not its prototype. What you want is

```
class testClass 
  username: 'Fred'

  testFunction: ->
    alert 'test'
```

Writing `this.testFunction =`, on the other hand, creates `testClass.testFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 class testClass 
    username: 'Fred'
    testFunction: ()->
      alert 'test'

  test = new testClass

  test.testFunction()
```

Coffeescript has classes as a first level concept; the `this.testfunction =` is wrong. You should just define it as a field of type function.